# IS this syntax ok for ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have this [app](https://github.com/michaeldv/fat_free_crm)  and while doing a `rake db:migrate` I get this error

```
      scope :my, lambda { |options = {}|
        includes(:permissions).
        where("#{quoted_table_name}.user_id     = :user OR " <<
              "#{quoted_table_name}.assigned_to = :user OR " <<
              "permissions.user_id              = :user OR " <<
              "#{quoted_table_name}.access = 'Public'", :user => options[:user] || User.current_user).
        order(options[:order] || "#{quoted_table_name}.id DESC").
        limit(options[:limit]) # nil selects all records
      }

 rake aborted!
 /Users/tamer/Sites/fat_free_crm/lib/fat_free_crm/permissions.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
      scope :my, lambda { |options = {}|
                                    ^
/Users/tamer/Sites/fat_free_crm/lib/fat_free_crm/permissions.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
```

Line 45 is the first line

```
scope :my, lambda { |options = {}|
```

Do i need to use ruby 1.9*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this wont' work in 1.8.7. Yes, it will work in 1.9.2. The more flexible block arguments were introduced as part of Ruby 1.9, including default arguments.

That said, this `scope` should really just be pushed off into a class method:

```
def self.my(options = {})
  includes(:permissions).
  where("#{quoted_table_name}.user_id     = :user OR " <<
        "#{quoted_table_name}.assigned_to = :user OR " <<
        "permissions.user_id              = :user OR " <<
        "#{quoted_table_name}.access = 'Public'", :user => options[:user] || User.current_user).
  order(options[:order] || "#{quoted_table_name}.id DESC").
  limit(options[:limit]) # nil selects all records
end
```

Same result, only it's 1.8.7 compatible.

Comment: can you explain what "scope :my, lambda { |options = {}|
"  this is doing

Comment: It just defines a class method, like I'm doing. It's just a Rails DSL to make it more explicit about what you're doing, but jackasses abuse them like this. It's great for quickies like `scope :expired, lambda { where('expiration < ?', Date.today) }` or `scope :blue, where(:color => 'blue')`. Those are much more concise than multi-line method definitions.